# SIGHUP signal handling to deamonize a command in Unix system programming

Tags: c, unix, signals, systems-programming, sigaction

I am reading a book about Unix system programming. In the book there is a function to create a daemon process.

Part of the code is not very clear to me, particularly the following:

```
struct sigaction    sa;
....
/* *Become a session leader to lose controlling TTY. */
if ((pid = fork()) < 0)
{
    err_quit("%s: can’t fork", cmd);
}
else if (pid != 0) /* parent */
{
    exit(0); //the parent will exit
}
setsid();

/* *Ensure future opens won’t allocate controlling TTYs. */
sa.sa_handler = SIG_IGN;
sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
sa.sa_flags = 0;
if (sigaction(SIGHUP, &sa, NULL) < 0)
{
    err_quit("%s: can’t ignore SIGHUP", cmd);
}
```

where

> `SIGHUP`is the signal sent to the controlling process (session leader)
>   associated with a controlling terminal if a disconnect is detected by
>   the terminal interface.

So basically the parent process calls `fork` and then exit. In this way we are guaranteed the child not a group leader. The child becomes a session leader with `setsid`.

I do not understand when the signal `SIG_UP` is generated: from the definition it seems it is generated when closing a Terminal window, but from the comment in the code

```
/* *Ensure future opens won’t allocate controlling TTYs. */
```

it seems it is generated in a different situation: when is it generated?

Secondly it wants to ignore this signal so it sets `sa.sa_handler = SIG_IGN` and then call `sigaction`. If it is ignoring the signal setting `SIG_IGN` as its handler, why is it setting the mask passed to `sigaction` as `sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);`? I mean if there is no handler, the mask set before executing the handler is not used: is it?

The complete function is the following:

```
void daemonize(const char *cmd)
{
    int i, fd0, fd1, fd2;
    pid_t pid;
    struct rlimit       rl;
    struct sigaction    sa;
    /* *Clear file creation mask.*/
    umask(0);
    /* *Get maximum number of file descriptors. */
    if (getrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE, &rl) < 0)
    {
        err_quit("%s: can’t get file limit", cmd);
    }
    /* *Become a session leader to lose controlling TTY. */
    if ((pid = fork()) < 0)
    {
        err_quit("%s: can’t fork", cmd);
    }
    else if (pid != 0) /* parent */
    {
        exit(0); //the parent will exit
    }
    setsid();
    /* *Ensure future opens won’t allocate controlling TTYs. */
    sa.sa_handler = SIG_IGN;
    sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
    sa.sa_flags = 0;
    if (sigaction(SIGHUP, &sa, NULL) < 0)
    {
        err_quit("%s: can’t ignore SIGHUP", cmd);
    }
    if ((pid = fork()) < 0)
    {
        err_quit("%s: can’t fork", cmd);
    }
    else if (pid != 0) /* parent */
    {
        exit(0);
    }
    /*
    *Change the current working directory to the root so
    * we won’t prevent file systems from being unmounted.
    */
    if (chdir("/") < 0)
    {
        err_quit("%s: can’t change directory to /", cmd);
    }
    /*
    *Close all open file descriptors.
    */
    if (rl.rlim_max == RLIM_INFINITY)
    {
        rl.rlim_max = 1024;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < rl.rlim_max; i++)
    {
        close(i);
    }
    /*
    *Attach file descriptors 0, 1, and 2 to /dev/null.
    */
    fd0 = open("/dev/null", O_RDWR);
    fd1 = dup(0);
    fd2 = dup(0);
    /*
    *Initialize the log file.
    */
    openlog(cmd, LOG_CONS, LOG_DAEMON);
    if (fd0 != 0 || fd1 != 1 || fd2 != 2) {
        syslog(LOG_ERR, "unexpected file descriptors %d %d %d", fd0, fd1, fd2);
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

Also I have an additional question. Why is `fork` called twice in the function?

Comment: Your book actually says `SIG_UP`? Hopefully that's a print error and not poor editing...

Comment: The signal is `SIGHUP`. The name is spelled in the same way even in different chapter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So basically ...

Yes, the parent process forks a child process, and that child does `setsid()` so that it will be the process group leader (and the only process) in the new process group, *and have no controlling terminal*.  That last part is the key.

(If there was a reason why the child process should run in the same process group as the parent process, one could use `int fd = open("/dev/tty", O_RDWR); if (fd != -1) ioctl(fd, TIOCNOTTY);` to detach from the controlling terminal. `setsid()` is easier, and it is usually preferable to have the child run in a new process group anyway, as it and its children can be sent a signal without affecting any other processes.)

Now, whenever a process that has no controlling terminal opens a terminal device (a tty or a pseudo-tty), that device will become its controlling terminal (unless the `O_NOCTTY` flag was used when opening the device).

Whenever the controlling terminal is disconnected, a SIGHUP signal is delivered to each process having that terminal as their controlling terminal. (That SIG_UP thing is just a typo. Signal names do not have an underscore, only the special handlers `SIG_DFL`, `SIG_IGN`, and `SIG_ERR` do.)

If the daemon process opens a terminal device for any reason -- for example, because a library wants to print an error message to a console, and opens `/dev/tty1` or similar to do so --, the daemon will inadvertently acquire a controlling terminal.  Other than interposing `open()`, `fopen()`, `opendir()`, and so on, to ensure their underlying `open()` flags will include `O_NOCTTY`, there is not much a daemon can do to ensure it will not inadvertently acquire a controlling terminal.  Instead, the easier option is to just assume that it might, and simply ensure that that does not cause too much trouble.  To avoid the most typical issue, dying from `SIGHUP` when the controlling terminal is disconnected, the daemon process can simply ignore the delivery of the `SIGHUP` signal.

In short, it is a belt-and-suspenders approach.  The `setsid()` detaches the process from the controlling terminal; and `SIGHUP` is ignored in case the daemon inadvertently acquires a controlling terminal by opening a tty device without using the `O_NOCTTY` flag.

Comment: First of all thank you for your answer. What about `sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);` in conjunction with `sigaction(SIGHUP, &sa, NULL) < 0)`? Why is it setting the mask for a `NULL` handler?

Comment: @FrancescoBoi: `.sa_mask` is the mask of signals blocked during the execution of the signal handler, in addition to whatever signals are blocked in the thread when the signal is delivered. It must be initialized to the empty set using `sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);`. It is common to leave it empty. The third parameter to `sigaction()` is not the handler, but a pointer to a `struct sigaction` filled with the details of the old signal action this new one replaced; or NULL if the information is not needed.

Comment: So is it just out of convention?

Comment: @FrancescoBoi: Not just convention, it is **required**. It initializes the `.sa_mask` member to a known state: empty mask.